# MAD formula for excel

Tags: excel, data-mining, formula, excel-formula

What are the set excel formula for calculating
1) Median Absolute Difference MAD

Answer (score 1):

For `interquartile range`

> If your data range is a1:a10 then the
>   interquantile range equation is
>   =percentile(a1:a10,0.75)-percentile(a1:a10,0.25)